# how to stop the execution after n-th continues query execution

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Is there any way to limit the continues query execution in postgres? I have a program to run the queries (10000+). But I need know is there any way to stop (break) the execution after exactly 10000 query.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: No context, no code, this is not a very useful question.

Comment: Actually I had a problem like this in my server. Hence, I would like to know what are the ways to do this. So, I can dig over into that and fix my problem. @ErwinBrandstetter I don't see like its not a very useful question. Because we have a very tricky solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in facility for this.

If all queries  execute on one connection you could use a debugger (gdb or msvc, depending on platform) to set a conditional breakpoint with a hit-count of 1000 in `exec_simple_query` and `exec_execute_message`.

Otherwise you'll have to do it client-side.

---

In general, wanting to do something like this suggests that you're probably dealing with an unrecognised underlying design issue, usually arising from failure to think about SQL as a language for working with *sets*.

For example, the following is a common anti-pattern in applications (pseudo-code):

```
foreach (i in some_array) {
    connection.execute("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id = ?", i);
}
```

where it's almost always better to instead use an `IN` list for small arrays, like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sometable 
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

or a join over a `VALUES` clause for large arrays, like:

```
WITH my_ids(id) AS (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4))
SELECT *
FROM sometable s 
INNER JOIN my_ids i
WHERE s.id = i.id;
```